# C# Capture command line output from custom commands using Process class

Tags: c#, command-line, cmd

I've my own custom commands for my windows application to execute specific operations in my application and it generates output and display it on the command prompt whether specific operation was completed or display error message if it failed for some reason.

Below is the sample custom command for my app:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\SampleApp> START MYAPP \TEST \GETDATA "SAMPLE.TXT"
Authorization successful.
Data retrieved successfully.

C:\ProgramFiles\SampleApp> START MYAPP \TEST \GETDAATA "SAMPLE.TXT"
Authorization successful.
Invalid command parameter.
```

Now, I tried to capture this output using Process class but ended up getting empty string all the time. (I've tried all the possibilities like invoking OutputDataReceived event, using StandaradOutput, and so on...)

Below is the sample that I've tried to read the command line output.

```
                    Process cliProcess = new Process();
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.FileName = meter.MeterIpAddress;                        
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "START \TEST \GETDATA "SAMPLE.TXT";
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workingDirectory) ? workingDirectory : string.Empty;
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    cliProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    cliProcess.Exited += CliProcess_Exited;
                    cliProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(CliProcess_OutputDataReceived);
                    cliProcess.ErrorDataReceived += CliProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
                    cliProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    cliProcess.Start();
                    cliProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    cliProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

private void CliProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                   {
                      if (e.Data != null)
                      {
                          temp.AppendLine(e.Data);
                      }

                   }

private void CliProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            temp.AppendLine(e.Data);
        }
    }
```

Any other way around?

Comment: What exactly have you tried, how exactly are you trying to start a process? Did you perhaps forget to enable redirection of the standard output channel? Is the output perhaps going to the error channel? If the program you are starting your own program, check in its source code how the output is created and written there.

Comment: @elgonzo Hey thanks for the response, I've updated my post with sample what I tried.

Comment: Your problem is that you use `cmd`'s `start` command (to learn what it really does, open a cmd window and type `help start`). But why are you using `cmd` at all? Based on your description, I believe that the program you want to capture the output from is an executable, which can (and normally should be) started directly. Thus, try starting it directly and see whether you can capture its output. (If the program is a batch file instead, keep using `cmd` but without the `start` command.)

Comment: How can i call cmd.exe without start function? And I can't start my program .exe directly as I'm running silently using command line arguments and I've to run like that.

Comment: "_And I can't start my program .exe directly as I'm running silently using command line arguments and I've to run like that_". Wrong. Where did you get that idea from? You don't need cmd.exe to run an executable with or without command line arguments. Just start your exe (it is called "executable" for a reason) with the desired command line arguments directly. If you insist on believing to need cmd.exe to start your program (but why would you?), you can learn the different ways how to use cmd.exe to start some program by opening a cmd window and typing `cmd /?`.

Comment: Actually here my intention is to run my app through CLI commands not through GUI, where my app will take the command and execute it and gives the result in the command prompt (where I'm writing my result string using console.writeline() after my operation was completed)

Comment: This is too vague. I have no idea what you mean when you say "CLI commands"? Are you talking about command line arguments for the program, or does the program read user input through the console in normal operation?

Comment: Yes. Command line arguments for the program. I'm running my app through command line arguments which will give output as string and I'm unable to capture using above code snippet.

Comment: Of course you can run your executable directly using the Process class and provide command line arguments to it (as i already said). The property used to provide command line arguments for the process being started is `Process.StartInfo.Arguments`. Heck, you even already make use of the proeprty in your code above to pass command line arguments to cmd.exe. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) I don't know where your confusion originates from, but please forget what you believe about how to use the Process class. Use the Process class to start the executable directly (instead of cmd.exe) and assign the commandline arguments for that executable to `Process.StartInfo.Arguments`. No more fussing around with cmd.exe ;-)

Comment: I got it. Let me try that and thanks for your time. :-)

Comment: @elgonzo It's working fine. Thank you so much for your time and inputs. Also can you please post/Answer the above content, so that I can accept your answer.